# How do I point my reserved domain to a Django EC2 instance?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

Ok so I'm hosting a Django EC2 instance right now using `ngrok http 8000` and leaving it running. It's doing fine but a lot of browsers are blocking the traffic to my site. I need to make my reserved domain (I have some on Amazon and some on 1 and 1) to my `123.4.5.67:8000` public IPv4 IP or just my public IPv4 DNS on my EC2.

What I need in a nutshell is example.com to redirect to `123.4.5.67:8000` while still saying example.com in the url.

So far I have heard of Apache, WSGI, and nginx. None of them have worked for me, but maybe I haven't gotten the right direction.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure that you need to make this change wherever you host your domain. The only way i was able to do this with my personal server was to point to port 80instead of 8000